# How to match a whole word containing special characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, oniguruma

I have words to match using only a single pattern. The criteria are one of the following:

- it contains a number or an underscore at the first letter, OR
- at least one special character (excluding underscore) within the word:

*Should match*

```
3testData
3test_Data
_testData
_test3Data
%data%
test%BIN%data
te$t&$#@daTa
```

*Should NOT match*

```
test_Data3
```

So far, I have managed to match some of them through:

```
[\p{^Alpha}]\S+
```

Except for the words where special characters are inside the word

> **3testData**
>   **3test_Data**
>   **_testData**
>   **_test3Data**
>   **%data%**
>   **test**%BIN%data
>   **test**%BIN%data
>   **te**$t&$#@daTa

Comment: What is the rule here? You may as well use `.+` or `\S+`

Comment: Hi Manu, welcome to stack overflow. Can you please elaborate what do you want as output?

Comment: thanks! my goal is to get a whole-word match for each word. These words are from a code so I'm trying to get to a pattern specific to matching words with numbers and underscore at the first letter, and special characters at any part of the word.

Comment: to clarify, the bold font on the output is the match I got from using the regex pattern I used.

Comment: If you want to match them all where the first character can be a character, numeric, an underscore or a percentage sign, try [`^[\w%]\S+$`](https://regex101.com/r/Ry8ERx/1)

Comment: You may try this: `[\w%\_]+`. But I'm not very sure what special characters you are looking for. https://regex101.com/r/do6T5N/1

Comment: yeah sorry I forgot to indicate that. that's what I am trying to say on my first sentence, 
- number and underscore on first letter only
- any special character at any position

Comment: @Manu But then `%data%`
`test%BIN%data`
`te$t&$#@daTa` should not match because those start with `t` or a `%` right? If the words are part of a larger text and lookbehinds are supported, try [`(?<=\s|^)[\d_]\S+(?=\s|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/7bmbEV/1)

Comment: ah you're right, it should be number/underscore on first letter OR any other special character at any position.

Comment: @Manu Do  [`(?<=\s|^)[\d_]\S+(?=\s|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/7bmbEV/1) or [`^[\d_]\S+$`](https://regex101.com/r/dIzQhT/1) work for you?

Comment: @Jenny not really. If a number or underscore appear as the first character, it's a  match but they can still be anywhere in the word

Comment: What is the difference to what I was saying? Maybe we should discuss this in a chat to clarify what exactly you mean. It looks like nobody understands it 100%.

Comment: @Thefourthbird doesn't seem to match those with special characters within the word.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly I thought what you're saying was something like "3test77_data" would not match. It still is because there's a number on the first character.

Comment: I think you are ambiguous. First you say that a number may only appear as first character and then you say that any special character (excl. underscore) can follow. But that would also include numbers.

Comment: @Manu If it either starts with a digit or an underscore OR there must be a special character in the word and the word can occur in a larger text and lookbehinds are suppoerted try [`(?<=\s|^)(?:[\d_]\S+|\S*[%@#$]\S*)(?=\s|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/hONmSf/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird  Nice, it works! lookbehind is supported but I am still trying to learn them. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly sorry about that. I posted faster than how I gathered my thoughts on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If lookbehinds are supported, you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either starting with an underscore or a digit OR in the other case matching zero or more times not a whitespace character, at least a special character using a character class followed by matching zero or more times not a whitespace character again.

`(?<=\s|^)(?:[\d_]\S+|\S*[%@#$]\S*)(?=\s|$)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hONmSf/1)

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\s|^)` Positive lookbehind to assert what is on the left is either a whitespace character or the start of the string
- `(?:` Start non capturing group

  - `[\d_]\S+` Match a digit or an underscore followed by matching one or more times not a whitespace character
  - `|` Or
  - `\S*[%@#$]\S*` Match zero or more times not a whitespace character followed by matching what is specified in the character class and the match zero or more times not a whitespace character again
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `(?=\s|$)` Positive lookahead to assert that what follows is a whitespace character or the end of the string

Comment: thank you! Just a follow-up, [%@#$] this part does not cover all other special characters, right? So I need to add more if I want it to be matched.

Comment: @Manu Yes that is correct. Note that  this part `\S*[%@#$]\S*` will also match a single special character due to the zero or more times repetition of `\S*`. Perhaps you could update your questions with all the requirements from the comments.

Answer (score 0):

if i get question right you search for a starting % and an ending % into a string. Assuming there's only one possible by string you could use indexOf and lastIndexOf looking like

```
function searchTagIn(symbol, str){ let chk=str.indexOf(symbol);
 if(  chk>-1){
  if(str.lastIndexOf(symbol)!=chk){
   return str.substring(chk,str.lastIndexOf(symbol);
  }
 }return;
}
```

Comment: thanks and welcome fellow newcomer!

However, this isn't what I want, sorry for not being really clear. As much as possible, I am trying to match all the words with a single regex pattern without having to resort to creating a function.